# What can I learn from the differentials of a series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I apologize in advance for my language - I am not in any sort of mathematical community so I do not know the proper terms for the things I am talking about.

I have two series’ each containing an infinite number of integers.  The sequences of numbers within each series appear random.

On the first series I look at the differences between adjacent numbers.  I’ll call this diff1 (so if the first series was 2,4,8,16,... then diff1 is 2,4,8,...).  The result is a new series when I take diff2 all the numbers are the same.  Then I take diff3 and it’s 0’s across the board.

On the second series I do the exact same thing but the diffs don’t converge to 0.  All the diffs seem kind of random but at some point (Diff3) all subsequent diffs have an AVERAGE of 0.  The distribution of subsequent diffs still look random but the average is 0 for ever one.

On to my question.  What have I learned about the 2 series’?  What is it telling me when after a sequence of diffs the diffs reduce to 0?  What is it telling me when after a sequence of diffs the series can be infinitely diff’d and each diff will have an average of 0?

Thanks a lot for the advice.

Matt

Comment: Show us your series. Talking in a vacuum is unproductive.